# countifs formula returns #ref! after vba code changes one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have built some code that draws data from another excel to the main one in sheet2 and in sheet1. I have some formulas, especially `countifs`, to calculate the data from sheet2, but whenever code runs the `countifs` formulas got `#REF!` error even if I select whole columns in it.

Is there any efficient way to solve this? I did that with `countifs` because I thought it would speed thins up (as i have 32 fields to calculate).

```
=countifs(Details!#REF!;Statictic!A14;Details!#REF!;Statictic!A17)
```

Comment: Is your code deleting columns?

Comment: yes it does, in fact i have cells.delete thing to have space for new data.

Comment: Can you do it by clearing the contents instead of deleting the columns?

Comment: i think it worked! many thanks for help Scott.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'lock' the columns for COUNTIFS with INDIRECT. If you always want the second and fourth column for the ranges then,

```
=countifs(indirect("Details!B:B"); Statictic!A14; indirect("Details!D:D"); Statictic!A17)
```

Text that looks like a range reference will not change even if the columns are deleted but INDIRECT is required to convert the text to workable range references.

You can also use INDEX which is non-volatile.

```
=countifs(index(Details!A:XFD, 0, 2); Statictic!A14; index(Details!A:XFD, 0, 4); Statictic!A17)
```

Assuming that you don't delete Details!A:A, this will always reference the second and fourth column.